# Magento : Moving content to the review tab on the product page

Tags: javascript, css, magento, view, tabs

On this page http://www.acuity-sports.com/procage-batting-tunnel-net-42.html

I'm trying to move the review content to the review tab on the page.

This is the what is at the bottom of the view.phtml before the upsell.

```
<div class="box-add-review">
                <div class="box-add-review-inner">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_reviews') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('review_form') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I added:

    
     <?php if( $product_reviews ): ?>
      <div id="yt_tabitem_reviews">
       <div class="box-add-review">
           <div class="box-add-review-inner">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_reviews') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('review_form') ?>
           </div>
          </div>
      </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open [magento]\app\design\frontend\default\default\layout\catalog.xml

find and addTab

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">

<reference name="content">
........
 <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
        <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="review">                      
        <alias>review</alias>
        <title>Add Reviews</title>
        <block>review/product_view_list</block>
        <template>review/product/view/list.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </block> 
.......
</reference>

</catalog_product_view>
```

[magento]\app\design\frontend\default\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('info_tabs') ?>
```